# Having two .aar files in a project and one being a dependency to the other

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I need to add two .aar files in one of my projects.

Let's call them **A.aar** and **B.aar**.

I add A.aar to the project and I get an error of a missing dependency, because B.aar is actually the dependency used within A.aar that is missing. But A.aar was built without it so that's why I'm trying to figure out how I could add them both to the project and have this situation work.

Right now I created a directory let's call it **Shared ** that has only a **build.gradle** file, which looks like this:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('A.aar'))
artifacts.add("default", file('B.aar'))
```

this directory is added in the modules like this:

```
api project(":Shared")
```

the outcome right now:

A.aar is being added properly and I can work with it, I can import needed files and use them.
No exceptions or errors are showing indicating that B.aar is not present.
When it get's to a point where I need to use something from A.aar that uses something from B.aar the flow stops at that point. No errors no exceptions to tell me if it can't access something from B.aar.

I hope I was able to describe the issue in a way that is understandable.

My question is if there is a possibility to add to separate .aar files into a project, one being a dependency within the other like in case of A.aar having B.aar as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figured it out, and these were the issues:

1. each .aar file needs to be placed in separate modules
2. I had missing dependencies for B.aar, even though there was no error showing this